# Make Properties/Functions Bold in Intellisense

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to Highlight Properties/Functions on your custom classes in intellisense? It's used lots in the Framework and it really helps show main features of a class. I've tried looking for an attribute because I know the obsolete attribute influences the display, but no luck.

EDIT

The original question is flawed because of my misunderstanding of how intellisense displays items. As explained in answers the bold items are new properties/functions created by a child class, in other words the Bold is done automatically.

I am still interested if there is any other way to highlight certain functions, I am using ReSharper if that helps.

Comment: Random question: are the bold properties / methods in Intellisense an arbitrary set of what looks to be hand-picked "main features" of a class, or just ones that aren't inherited from a superclass?

Comment: I don't think so.  Even if you could, would you really want your objects riddled with "main feature"?  The only reason obsolete shows anything on the UI is because it is meant to warn the user consuming the object.  I think you should concentrate on making your objects self explanatory.  You can always add comments to the methods, for further clarification.

Comment: Another approach would be returning interfaces that only expose the "main features" on your code, instead of implementation objects with internal clutter.

Comment: I thought the bold properties/methods were the ones implemented directly on the class in question, rather than being inherited from the base?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bold entries in IntelliSense are the members directly implemented on the class, with the inherited properties and methods shown in a regular font.

If it helps, you can hide 'advanced' entries from the list using the [[EditorBrowsable] attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx). In this context, 'advanced' means 'hidden when the Hide Advanced Members setting is enabled via Tools | Options | Text Editor | C#'.